# reshaping 1000x500 matrix to 100x500 in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a 1000x500 matrix (1000 rows each corresponding to 1min Counts and 500 columns corresponding to different height levels). I want to compute 10 min averages (using nanmean) of the counts, which means I want my final matrix to be 100x500. Is there an easy way to do this ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape into a 10-row matrix, apply `nanmean` along each column, and reshape back to a 500-column matrix. Let `M` denote your matrix:

```
result = reshape(nanmean(reshape(M, 10, [])), [], size(M,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can do:

```
% assuming data is your 1000x500 matrix
avgs = zeros(100, 500);
inds = 1:10;
for i = 0:99 
    avgs(i + 1, :) = nanmean(data(i * 10 + inds, :))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the matrix into a cell of a hundred `10-by-500` matrices; `nanmean` them along the columns and then put them in a matrix again:

```
avgs = cell2mat(cellfun(@(X) nanmean(X,1), mat2cell(data,10*ones(100,1),[500]), 'uni', 0));
```

Comment: Luis's answer accomplishes this without needing cells, or the notoriously slow `cellfun`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Indeed; yet there's no harm in having a few alternatives to choose from. (In fact Luis posted his solution just while I was writing my initial solution: `avgs = squeeze(nanmean(reshape(data.',500,10,[]),2)).';`, which of course made me rethink the answer because of the superfluous transposes)